# In GridMVC filter not working after clicking on apply whole grid is disapering

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Filtering is Not Working once after clicking on apply in search option whole grid is disappearing, And note that enabling a partial view in main view

```
@model IEnumerable<StatementReconciliation.Models.StatementDisplay>
@using GridMvc.Html
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Gridmvc.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.6.4.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js")"></script>
<div style="height:612px;overflow-x:scroll" class="container-fluid">
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        @Html.Grid(Model).Named("StatementDisplay").Columns(columns =>
   {
       columns.Add(c => c.Vendor_Code).Titled("Vendor Code").Filterable(true);
       columns.Add(c => c.Invoice_Number).Titled("Invoice Number").Filterable(true);
       columns.Add(c => c.Invoice_Date).Titled("Invoice Date").Filterable(true);
       columns.Add(c => c.Due_Date).Titled("Due Date").Filterable(true);
       columns.Add(c => c.PO_Number).Titled("PO Number").Filterable(true);
       columns.Add(c => c.Amount).Titled("Amount").Filterable(true);
       columns.Add(c => c.Currency).Titled("Currency").Filterable(true);
       columns.Add(c => c.Reference_Number).Titled("Reference Number").Filterable(true);
       columns.Add(c => c.Reference_Comment).Titled("Reference Comment").Filterable(true);
       columns.Add(c => c.Stat_Recd_Date).Titled("Received Date").Filterable(true);
       columns.Add(c => c.StatementDate).Titled("Statement Date").Filterable(true);
       //columns.Add(c => c.AutomatedComments).Titled("Automated Comments").Filterable(true);
       //columns.Add(c => c.UserComment).Titled("User Comments").Filterable(true);
       columns.Add()
       .Encoded(false)
       .Sanitized(false)
       .SetWidth(30);

   }).Sortable(true)

    }
</div>
```

This is the code which iam using.